# python format a files modified date

Tags: python, datetime, format

I am looking at an example of getting a file date:

```
import os.path, time 
file = r'C:\Users\...\18.organizer.v3.012119.pdf'
print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

This returns: last modified: Sat Feb  9 18:16:48 2019
I am not seeing anywhere in the documentation that %s formats to the format above.

```
print( time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))) produces
```

Sat Feb  9 18:16:48 2019

How do I format the os.path.getmtime(file) to a simple YYYY-MM-DD format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: How do I format the os.path.getmtime(file) to a simple YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: You’ve just repeated what was in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `os.path.getmtime()` returns a POSIX timestamp, you can use the `date.fromtimestamp()` method in the datetime module.

```
from datetime import date
print(date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

Comment: Do I need to import something in addition to what I did above? I am getting the following error: NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: It should work as long you import `os.path` and `from datetime import date`. Make sure you copied the line correctly.